# Create a node in neo4j if not present.

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to create a node only if it not present in the graph. 
Example node A is already present, So my query should Check if node A is already present if not create a node. I don't want to use constraint here.
It's needed for load data from mysql without duplicate entries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you want the `MERGE` keyword:

> MERGE either matches existing nodes and binds them, or it creates new data and binds that. It’s like a combination of MATCH and CREATE that additionally allows you to specify what happens if the data was matched or created.
>
> For example, you can specify that the graph must contain a node for a user with a certain name. If there isn’t a node with the correct name, a new node will be created and its name property set.

Use whichever columns that make your rows in MySQL unique.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html